# Although I can reach ONOS CLI, I cannot reach http://localhost:8181/onos/ui

Tags: sdn, onos

I have been worked with ONOS controller for a time. Today, I started onos with "bazel run onos-local --clean debug" command. Onos started to work, I can reach CLI of controller. However I cannot reach to  http://localhost:8181/onos/ui GUI as I used before. Is there any suggestion or idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ONOS community have not enabled GUI application by default in the latest versions.
if you want to access gui you have to enable the proper application.

here is how to do that:
first access the CLI and type:

```
app activate org.onosproject.gui2
```

the other way is to set GUI application in default running apps.